# [Javascript][React] Get property of Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code:

```js
const [obj, setObj] = useState(() => ({
    a: valueA,
    b: valueB,
    get values() {
            if (!this.a || !this.b) {
            return [];
        }
        // code...
    }
    return [this.a, this.b]
    },

}));
```

Values update:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const copyObj = {...obj}; // object copy
    copyObj.a = valueA;
    copyObj.b = valueB;

    setObj(copyObj);
}, [valueA, valueB]);
```

After executing setObj:

```js
console.log(obj.values); // still previous value
```

Question is: <br/>

Can I use get property with setting `this` value to `copyObj`?

Comment: I've fount the solution by trying out Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor and Object.defineProperty method. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous. it would be best if you waited till values are set. use `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {

   console.log(obj)
   
}, [obj]);
```